# C# extract Cell Information from In-Sight Explorer (Cognex)

Tags: c#, cognex

Does anyone have experience using C# and a Cognex camera? I wish to extract information from an in-sight explorer spreadsheet and display it on a C# program using:
 `Cognex.InSight.Cell.CvsCellFloat`
but I don't know how. I am new to C# so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you have already purchased and installed the In-Sight SDK. If not, please contact your local Cognex distributor.

Here's instructions for a very simple demo application:

1. Start Visual Studio (I'm using Visual Studio 2012).
2. Create a new Visual C# Windows Forms Application.
3. Choose "Add Reference..." from the Project menu.
4. Add the framework assembly reference 'Cognex.InSight'.  Also
   consider adding 'Cognex.InSight.Controls.Display' if you want to
   display camera images (not covered here).
5. Click the OK button to close the Reference Manager.
6. Add 'Load' and 'FormClosed' event handlers for your main Form.
7. Edit the code for the form.
8. Add 'using Cognex.InSight;' and 'using Cognex.InSight.Cell;' to the top of the form code.
9. Add a CsvInSight object to the form.
10. Add code to your form similar to that shown below.

Note: The ResultsChanged event doesn't only occur on an inspection.  I would suggest you add an inspection counter to your spreadsheet (using an Accumulate function triggered by event A0) and add code at the start of the ResultsChanged event to check if the inspection count has changed since the occurrence of the ResultsChanged event.  If the counter hasn't changed, simply exit the ResultsChanged event handler by using a 'return;' statement.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    CvsInSight insight = new CvsInSight();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        insight.Connect("127.0.0.1", "admin", "", false, false);
        insight.ResultsChanged += insight_ResultsChanged;
    }

    void insight_ResultsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Here: Consider inserting code to check that this event
        // has been triggered by an image acquisition

        CvsResultSet results = insight.Results;
        // Note the reference below to row 10, column 3 (cell D10)
        CvsCell cell = results.Cells.GetCell(10, 3);
        if (cell == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Cell D10 is null");
            return;
        }
        if (cell.DataType != CvsCellDataType.FloatingPoint) {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Unexpected data type at cell D10");
            return;
        }
        CvsCellFloat floatCell = (CvsCellFloat)cell;
        MessageBox.Show("Floating point value at cell D10 is: " + floatCell.Value.ToString());
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        insight.Disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: i can do that with some modifications of course on Xamarin.Android too?

Comment: I very much doubt that you could use this with Xamarin Android because the Cognex In-Sight SDK is not supported on that platform.

Comment: SDK is still  locked into 32 bit windows. Cognex said we can use Native Mode commands to do the same interactions if the platform is non win32.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what is those native mode commands? a simple example for Xamarin.Android command would be great

Comment: Native mode commands are text commands which can be sent over a telnet connection. The commands are documented in the In-Sight Explorer help file. In-Sight Explorer can be downloaded from [cognex.com](http://www.cognex.com).  I'm not very familiar with Xamarin, but I believe you will need to use the [Socket](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Net.Sockets.Socket/) class for the communications

Comment: Note that you will need to connect to port 23 on the camera and you will need to supply a username and password when the camera asks for them.  The default username is 'admin' and the default password is blank ('').  You can also use Native Mode communications over RS232 in which case you do not need to supply a username or password.