# C# write cell to In-Sight Explorer (cognex)

Tags: c#, cognex

I found this page where there is an example for extract cell information from an Insight-Explorer but... what about to write into the cell from a c# application?

[C# extract Cell Information from In-Sight Explorer (Cognex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499960/c-sharp-extract-cell-information-from-in-sight-explorer-cognex?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: nobody use this software application ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control the cells in the current job file of an In-Sight camera using C#, here is the method that has worked for me. Please note, I'm using In-Sight Explorer v5.9.0, but I've tested this on earlier versions too and it still works.

**NOTE**: Without a Cognex In-Sight SDK license, you will not be able to run this application within Visual Studio. You will have to build the project and then run the executable directly.

1. Open **Visual Studio**
2. Create a new **Console App (.NET Framework)** project
3. I'm using **.NET Framework 4.7.2**
4. Right-click on the project in the solution explorer and add a **reference** to the Cognex.InSight.dll file (It is typically located here: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Cognex\In-Sight\5.x.x.x\Cognex.InSight.dll)**
5. Set the target platform to **x86**
6. Paste the code, below, into your project
7. Change the **username**, **password** and **ipAddress** variables to match what's setup for your camera
8. **Build**
9. Go to the **Debug** folder and find the executable that was created after building the project
10. **Double-click** the executable to run it

```c#
using System;
using Cognex.InSight;

namespace ChangeInSightCellValue2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string username = "admin";
            string password = "";
            string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";

            // Create camera object and connect to it
            CvsInSight camera = LogIntoCamera(ipAddress, username, password, true, false);

            // Define which cell you want to modify
            CvsCellLocation cell = new CvsCellLocation(2, 'C');

            // Modify the cell expression
            camera.SetExpression(cell, "Filter($A$0,0,0,0,80,100,320,440,0,0,3,3,1,128,128,128,1,1,0)", true);
        }

        // Log into camera
        private static CvsInSight LogIntoCamera(string sCamIP, string sCamUsername, string sCamPassword, bool forceConnect, bool connectAsynchronous)
        {
            // Create camera object
            CvsInSight insight = new CvsInSight();
            Console.WriteLine("Object created");

            IAsyncResult result;
            // Try logging into the camera on a different thread to prevent locking this one up
            Action action = () =>
            {
                // Connect to camera
                insight.Connect(sCamIP, sCamUsername, sCamPassword, forceConnect, connectAsynchronous);
            };

            result = action.BeginInvoke(null, null);

            if (result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5000))
                return insight;

            else
                return insight;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: If you're connected to the camera with In-Sight Explorer when you run this application, the In-Sight Explorer will disconnect from the camera and then try to reconnect after your application has disconnected from the camera.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Native Mode Commands to set the value of controls in the spreadsheet in In-Sight Explorer (as discussed in the question you linked to).  Note that you won't be able to write data to any cell - you will only be able to write to cells containing `EditInt()`, `EditFloat()`, `EditString()`, `CheckBox()`, etc functions.  Send the commands as text over a socket connection to the cameras port 23.  You will need to send a username and password to the camera when the connection is established.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Cognex SDK, use the following functions

- `CvsInSight.SetFloat(...)` to set EditFloat control values
- `CvsInSight.SetInteger(...)` to set EditInt control values
- `CvsInSight.SetListBoxIndex(...)` to select items in list boxes
- `CvsInSight.SetString(...)` to set EditString control values
- `CvsInSight.SetCheckBox(...)` to change the state of CheckBox controls